# How to generate counts of positive values by column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data tables that consist of several columns and many thousands of rows.
My data looks something like:

```
iteration V1  V2  V3  V4
1         -2  3   -4   1
2         -2  3   -3   4
3         -2  3    7   -8
4         -2  3   -4   2
5         -2  3   -4   -3
```

I have been trying to figure out how to calculate counts of positive values in each column, and the proportion of positive counts to all counts in a column.

This seems fairly simple but I can't figure out how to output a data.table that has counts by column in it.

I can do this by combining a bunch of the following statements, but there has to be a better way- any advice for a tired mind?

```
nrow(dat[v2>=0])
```

Comment: If you really have a `data.table`, maybe `dat[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x > 0))]` will be more efficient (avoids matrix conversion)

Comment: @DavidArenburg - although adding up the `iteration` column seems a bit odd - maybe `dat[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x > 0) ), .SDcols=-1]`

Comment: @thelatemail yeah, probably

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
df <- data.frame('V1'=c(-2, -2, -2, -2, -2), 'V2'=c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3), 'V3'=c(-4, -3, 7, -4, -4), 'V4'=c(1, 4, -8, 2, -3))
```

you could start by defining the number of rows as:

```
nRows <- dim(df)[1]
```

Then, you can define an auxiliary function as such:

```
calcStats <- function(x) {
  pos <- sum(df[, x] > 0)
  c("number of positives" = pos, "proportion of positives" = pos / nRows)
  }
```

and get the result with:

```
result <- as.data.frame(Map(calcStats, colnames(df)))

                        V1 V2  V3  V4
number of positives      0  5 1.0 3.0
proportion of positives  0  1 0.2 0.6
```

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work?  Please execute it line by line.   It works for me and gives the expected result....

Comment: I don't really understand all the downvotes....  Can someone explain why my answer is rejected?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but doe starters, OP asked about data.table

Comment: Judging from how the question is posed, the answer should be more than satisfactory.  Besides one could convert data frame to data table if that is really what he has in mind

Comment: Thanks ranlot! Your solution works. As some people have suggested I did frame the question from a data.table perspective but thanks for the effort.

Comment: If this is satisfactory, you may "accept" the answer